# Python IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to match 1000 images (listing) with 1000 labels which are are in "trainLabels" dataFrame. I had created this loop that worked well until I tried to remove those images that had low quallity. 
I have removed with the .drop() function the corresponding rows in the dataFrame trainLabels and I have reseted its index with .reset_index(), but I could not solve it. Any suggestions?

```
from PIL import Image 


img_rows, img_cols = 200, 200 # desired size for images 


immatrix = [] 
imlabel = [] 

for file in listing: 

    base = os.path.basename("../input/" + file) 
    fileName = os.path.splitext(base) [0] #consigue el nombre del archivo sin la extensión
    imlabel.append(trainLabels.loc[trainLabels.image==fileName,"level"].values[0]) 
    im = Image.open("../input/" + file)
    img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
    gray = img.convert("L") 
    immatrix.append(np.array(gray).flatten())
```

Error message

```
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>     <ipython-input-45-6c7731e1f46b> in <module>()
>           9     base = os.path.basename("../input/" + file)
>          10     fileName = os.path.splitext(base) [0] #consigue el nombre del archivo sin la extensión
>     ---> 11     imlabel.append(trainLabels.loc[trainLabels.image==fileName,"level"].values[0])
>          12     im = Image.open("../input/" + file)
>          13     img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
>     
>     IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: **English** please!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is written in a language other than English.

Comment: Hello, I have translated my question.